# Join/Intersection using mapReduce in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I want to perform join operation on two distinct sets of documents having one field in common. I have following setup.

**Collection A**

```
{
    "common_key" : "v1" ,
    "a2" : "v2",
    "a3" : "v3",
    .....
}
```

**Collection B**

```
{
    "common_key" : "v1" ,
    "b2" : "z2",
    "b3" : "z3",
    .....
}
```

Since mapReduce can only work on one collection I merged the contents of A and B into Collection `Combo` . Additionally, I added one more field `_dataType` to indicate whether it is of type A or B

**Collection combo = A + B**

```
{
    "common_key" : "v1" ,
    "b2" : "z2",
    "b3" : "z3",
    "_dataType" : "B",
    .....
}

{
    "common_key" : "v1" ,
    "a2" : "v2",
    "a3" : "v3",
    "_dataType" : "A",
    .....
}
```

I want to write a mapReduce function such that for all those documents that have same `common_key` for each data type A & B it should output

```
{
    "common_key" : v1 ,
    "A" : [
            { 
              "a2" : "v2",
              "a3" : "v3",
              ...
             },
             ...
           ],
    "B" : [
            {
                "b2" : "z2",
                "b3" : "z3",
                .....
           },
           ..
           ]
}
```

Any pointers or help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer using aggregation framework

```
db.coll.aggregate({
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$common_key",
        "A": {
            "$push": {
                "$cond": [
                    {
                        "$eq": [
                            "$_dataType",
                            "A"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "a2": "$a2",
                        "a3": "$a3"
                        // you have to put all A dataType field here
                    }, 
                    {}
                ]
            }
        },
        "B": {
            "$push": {
                "$cond": [
                    {
                        "$eq": [
                            "$_dataType",
                            "B"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "b2": "$b2",
                        "b3": "$b3"
                        // you have to put all B dataType field here
                    },
                    {}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Cons: you have to write all fields of A and B dataTypes to project them and you'll have and empty object on each array (A and B)